# target this carousel only, multiple carousel on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a basic carousel twice on my page using the code below

```
$('.next').bind('click', function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
         $('.next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('.prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('.prev').bind('click', function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('.prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('.next').attr('disabled', null);
});
```

here is the html

```
<div class="shareBox">
<p class="highlight">
    <button class="prev linkBtn" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
    <button class="next linkBtn">Next</button>
</p>
<div class="mask">
    <ul class="shareBoxList slides">

        <li class="item">

        </li>


        <li class="item">

        </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

I want to only target the one that I am clicking through but am not sure where to add the jquery this in the function.

Thanks,

Sat

Comment: Please show your HTML so we can see what container to restrict the selection to.

Comment: html added to the code

Answer (score 1):

Without HTML it is hard, but here is the logic:

```
$('.next').bind('click', function() {
    var curCarouselNode = $(this).closest('.shareBox');
    curCarouselNode.find('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
    if (curCarouselNode.find('.current').hasClass('last')) {
         curCarouselNode.find('.next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    curCarouselNode.find('.prev').attr('disabled', null);
});
```

So what we do is get the highest carousel element of the clicked item. Then use it to find the elements which you wanted to interact with.

Comment: ive added the html to the post

Comment: Edited my answer according to your HTML.